# show Response Body from Rest API in seperate lines

Tags: angular, rest, swagger

I have an Angular2 Form with validations coming via REST API server which comes in format as shown below ( multiple validation errors , in some case )

```
[
  "Management Date must be within six months",
  "Management Time Hour is Invalid. Please enter the hours only in between 1 
    to 12",
  "Management Time Mins is Invalid. Please enter the Mins only in between 00 
   to 59"
]
```

on .ts file, i am accessing these messages like below -

```
.subscribe(
  data => {
   if(condition = true){
    this.clear();
    this.success(data);
    }else{
    this.clear();
    this.error(data);
    }
```

HTML, has a div that shows the styled message -

```
    <div class="col-md">
     <alert></alert>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

now, when I am trying to display the validation messages from the API Response Body, but it displays as below in the HTML page -

```
   ["Management Date must be within six months", "Management Time Hour is Invalid. Please enter the hours only in between 1 to 12", "Management Time Mins is Invalid. Please enter the Mins only in between 00 to 59"]
```

but I want to achieve the it like this -

```
    Management Date must be within six months
    Management Time Hour is Invalid. 
    Please enter the hours only in between 1 to 12
    Management Time Mins is Invalid. Please enter the Mins only in between 00 to 59
```

Any pointers on this? Greatly appreciate the responses and insights. Am novice-serverside-developer learning a TON in short amount of time, so many small questions popping up!!

Thank you, in advance.

UPDATE: this is the Alert Service I used to implement the alert messaging in my code. 
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/06/25/angular-2-4-alert-toaster-notifications

Comment: show `alert` directive

Comment: why can't you just do a split

Comment: what does your alert component look like?

Comment: I added the alert service details that I implemented exactly in my code.